# Citymaps develop in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, citymaps

When I develop my application with citymaps service to load a base map, I have serval questions as follows：

1. When I sync the project with grade file，android studio prompt that mini-sdk version no smaller than 15，so I must change mini-sdk to 15，why？
2. Atfer I sync your gradle file in my project，the software does not prompt the error，but when I run the application，the library is not found and the 
   software give me tips to add the library to the classpath，why is it so？
3. I want to locate the current position，Whether or not I need to get my position's latitude and longitude set to the method that you provider in your api reference? Does any method directly to locate the current position? Please tell me where is it? thanks!
4. When I load the map with the newest method like this:

   ```
   CitymapsMapFragment fragment = (CitymapsMapFragment)fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
   ```

   the map is loading very well but does't show an arrow in my current position，if I create my map with additional options，`setContentView(mapView)`. When the map is loading out I can find an arrow in that position. Why is it so？

Comment: "Whether or not I need to get my position's latitude and longitude set to the method that you provider in your api reference?" -> I have no idea what that means ... But I gathered you're asking several questions in one post, which I would not advise unless you're not interested in getting answers. Please take the time to go through the help section which explains how to ask a good question that will receive good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a developer on the Citymaps SDK.  I will do my best to answer all your questions

1) Yes, the Citymaps SDK does require a minimum SDK version of 15 (a.k.a Ice Cream Sandwich).  We made this decision based off of the APIs we wanted to use as well as the usage statistics of various Android versions (roughly 95% of Android users worldwide are running SDK 15 and higher).

2) If you are including the Citymaps project using gradle's sync, you shoud have no problems building and running our library.  Make sure to double check your gradle string.  If you still receive and error, it would be helpful to see the stack trace.

3) If the location services are not being triggered on startup, you can try calling `fragment.getMapView().startUpdatingLocation()`.  This should force the system to start tracking your GPS position.

4) Answer to #3 should solve this

Let me know if you have any follow ups.  Thank you for trying our SDK, and we hope you can make great use of it.